# Trying to make login and register form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a form that can create new users and passwords that store the Values from the input  tag when the user clicks on the register button.

But when I click register it's not adding the username and password value into the empty array.

**JavaScript Code**

```
// user need to create new username 
// writeing value in username and password inputs and than click registar
// after registar been clicked add inputs values into an array


var newUser = document.querySelector('.input_username').value;
var newPass = document.querySelector('.input_password').value;
let btnLogin = document.querySelector('.btn_login')
let btnRegistar = document.querySelector('.btn_registar')


let usernames = [];
let passwords = [];

function addUser(){

   let userCreate = usernames.push(newUser);
   let passCreate = passwords.push(newPass); 
   console.log(userCreate);
   console.log(passCreate);
   

}

btnRegistar.addEventListener('click', addUser);
```

**HTML CODE**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="div_main">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label for="">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="input_username" value=""> <br/>
        <label for="">Password</label> 
        <input type="text" class="input_password" value=""><br/>
        <button class="btn_login">Login</button><br/><br/>  
        <button class="btn_registar">Registar</button>
        <h2>Login Status: <span class="span_result"> </span></h2>

    </div>
    


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is what I'm getting in the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJwyf.png)

Answer (score 2):

As someone mention in the comment section, `push` is returning the length of the array, not the values.

Instead, use `concat()` method.

And if you take `.value` from your HTML element, declare them inside your function, otherwise, if they are declared in the global scope, they will usually be empty.

```js
// user need to create new username 
// writeing value in username and password inputs and than click registar
// after registar been clicked add inputs values into an array

let btnLogin = document.querySelector('.btn_login')
let btnRegistar = document.querySelector('.btn_registar')
let passwords = [];
let usernames = [];

function addUser(){

var newUser = document.querySelector('.input_username').value;
var newPass = document.querySelector('.input_password').value;

   usernames = usernames.concat(newUser);
   passwords = passwords.concat(newPass);
   console.log(usernames);
   console.log(passwords);
}

btnRegistar.addEventListener('click', addUser);
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="div_main">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label for="">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="input_username" value=""> <br/>
        <label for="">Password</label> 
        <input type="text" id="" class="input_password" value=""><br/>
        <button class="btn_login">Login</button><br/><br/>  
        <button class="btn_registar">Registar</button>
        <h2>Login Status: <span class="span_result"> </span></h2>

    </div>
    


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed to concat, and put the input values inside the function, but i see in console it's print an empty array.

Comment: because concat does not change the existing array. It returns a new one. The existing usernames and passwords array will never be changed. It should be `usernames = usernames.concat(newUser);` instead.

Comment: @maerzman Thanks, you're right. I've `console.log`ed the wrong thing.
@Dor It's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing userCreate and passCreate variables but you want to print the arrays

instead of

```
console.log(userCreate);
console.log(passCreate);
```

do this

```
console.log(usernames);
console.log(passwords);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are outputting hold the value true or false either your action has been processed or not. If you want to return the actual value that has been submitted try

```
Console.log(usernames);
Console.log(passwords)
```

This will return an array for all the data pushed. You can also perform

```
Console.log(usernames[0])
```

To return only the first submitted value.

Comment: i change the code to this - console.log(usernames);
   console.log(passwords);        but in console i see it's returning an empty string

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code

```js
// user needs to create a new username 
// writing value in username and password inputs and then click the register button
// after the button has been clicked add inputs values into an array

let btnLogin = document.querySelector('.btn_login')
let btnRegistar = document.querySelector('.btn_registar')
    
let usernames = [];
let passwords = [];

function addUser() {
    
    var newUser = document.querySelector('.input_username').value;
    var newPass = document.querySelector('.input_password').value;
    
    let userCreate = usernames.concat(newUser);
    let passCreate = passwords.concat(newPass);
    console.log(usernames);
    console.log(passwords);    
}
    
btnRegistar.addEventListener('click', addUser);
```

Here is what I'm getting in the console:

[image]

Comment: Please do not use answers to request or provide clarification, nor provides updates to the code in your question that should be an edit, please instead add an edit to your question (unless I am mistaken and this is the answer, in which case, please say so and I will retract my flag)

Comment: As stated under a different answer. Either use `usernames= usernames.concat(newUser);
    passwords = passwords.concat(newPass);` or `usernames.push(newUser);
    passwords.push(newPass);`